# Translating English to Symbolic Logic - Multiple Quantifiers

Tags: logic, quantifiers, logic-translation

Any hints on translating this English sentence into symbolic logic:

Something is between everything.

Comment: Is there any more context? "Between everything" is not really well-defined; "between" is usually between two elements. Moreover, if an element X is between everything, and X is part of everything, is X between itself?

Comment: @Gadi, when doing these translations from English to symbolic logic, I use Between(x, y, z) to say "x is between y and z."  Also, we use x != y && x !=z && y != z.

Comment: That doesn't answer Gadi's question. "everything" is not two elements, so it's unclear what $y$ and $z$ might be in your predicate.

Comment: The closest thing to this sentence that makes sense might be "There is something between any two things". That would be $\forall y\forall z\exists x\,\text{Between} (x,y,z)$.

Comment: This question is ill-formed and does not really parse.  I am having a Russell-paradox headache here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a quick list of rule of thumbs for translation:

- "Some" means $\exists x$
- "Every" and "All" mean $\forall x$
- "If x then y" or "x implies y" or "y only if x" mean $x\rightarrow y$
- "Either x, or y" means $x\lor y$
- "Both x and y" means $x\land y$
- "Not x" means $\lnot x$

The actual predicates you would have to fill in on your own.

As joriki and Gadi commented, "Between" is a trinary predicate (i.e. takes three variables, "x is between y and z") and the closest interpretation of the current sentence would be $\exists x\forall y\forall z\operatorname{Between}(x,y,z)$.

(Note the difference in the order I put the quantifiers and joriki put them, in his version between every two elements there is a third; in my version one specific element is between every two others, including itself.)

Comment: The other difference between you and joriki is that your statement is less likely to be true (though it does depend on what "Between" means).

Comment: @Henry, assume $x$ is God in the Judeo-Christian tradition, then god is between everything including itself and itself. :-)